# A button for open another screen not working in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
package com.example.lumeaanimalelor;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Iepure4 extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_iepure4);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openIepure5();
            }
        });


    }

    public void openIepure5() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Iepure5.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lumeaanimalelor">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LevelsActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Level1Menu"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Iepure1"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Iepure2"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Iepure3"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Iepure4"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Iepure5"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.224"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/iepure4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dacă te-ai hotărât să crești un iepure, e bine de știut că în ciuda faptului că Bugs Bunny mănâncă mereu morcovi, rădăcina morcovului (partea portocalie) nu trebuie consumată foarte des de către iepure pentru că are foarte multe zaharuri."
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.691" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mai departe ->"
        android:onClick="openIepure5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.723"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.884" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Run:

> D/ViewRootImpl@ed1b06e[Iepure4]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
>   D/ViewRootImpl@ed1b06e[Iepure4]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
>   W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token
>   android.os.BinderProxy@e300ac8 I/DecorView: createDecorCaptionView >>
>   DecorView@1ed689d[], isFloating: false, isApplication: true,
>   hasWindowDecorCaption: false, hasWindowControllerCallback: true
>   D/ViewRootImpl@ed1b06e[Iepure4]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
>   D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo()
>   DecorView@776eb7d[Iepure4]
>       getNavigationBarColor() -855310 D/ViewRootImpl@ed1b06e[Iepure4]: setWindowStopped(false) old=false D/ViewRootImpl@ed1b06e[Iepure4]:
>   MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1 D/InputMethodManager:
>   prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@776eb7d[Iepure4]
>       getNavigationBarColor() -855310

Comment: either use `onClick` in xml or `onClickListener` in the activity.

Comment: I tried  but same result...

Comment: post your error code

Comment: I don't have a error code. When I'm running app, the button do nothing and i have at run console what i added up, at "Run:".